# How can I get two time interval using sql?

Tags: sql, datediff

I want to subtract two dates,I used the sql datadiff,like this

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF('2016-01-04 22:59:01','2016-01-04 22:59:55') AS diff
 FROM time_interval;
```

But these is error,

[image]

Comment: Tag dbms used. Datediff is product specific!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't specifying the interval in the DATEDIFF function.

Your syntax should be DateDiff ( interval, date1, date2 [, firstdayofweek] [, firstweekofyear] )

Check out this link: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateDiff-Function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DateDiff('d','2016-01-04 22:59:01','2016-01-04 22:59:55') AS diff
FROM time_interval;
```

Function: DateDiff

Three parameters: Interval, Date1 and Date2.

Interval: String expression that is the interval of time you use to calculate the difference between date1 and date2. You may also use 's' for seconds, 'n' for minutes, 'h' for hours, 'ww' for weeks etc. Information taken from referenced link below.

Date1, Date2: Variant (Date). Two dates you want to use in the calculation.

Referenced from https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateDiff-Function-e6dd7ee6-3d01-4531-905c-e24fc238f85f

Comment: @tanxin If you could accept the answer that would be great :-)